# Swift: Generics and type constraints, strange behavior

Tags: swift

I can’t figure out how to perform a cast which would let me eventually to introduce some sort of dynamism working with generics.

Next piece of code does not compile. It shows this error:

> Cannot invoke 'createContainer' with an argument list of type
>   '(FooProtocol)' Expected an argument list of type '(T)'

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

class Foo : FooProtocol {
    func doSomething() {}
}

class Container<T : FooProtocol> {
    let someDataConformingFooProtocol : T

    init(someDataConformingFooProtocol : T) {
        self.someDataConformingFooProtocol = someDataConformingFooProtocol
    }
}

class AllTogether {

    init () {
        createContainer(Foo()) //So far, so good

        let foo2Mask : AnyObject = Foo()
        if let foo2MaskChecked = foo2Mask as? FooProtocol {
            createContainer(foo2MaskChecked)
            //ERROR: Cannot invoke 'createContainer' with an argument list of type '(FooProtocol)'
            //Expected an argument list of type '(T)'
        }

    }

    func createContainer<T : FooProtocol>(data: T){
        Container<T>(someDataConformingFooProtocol: data)
    }
}
```

Is this really the expected behaviour? Because personally I can’t understand what or why the compiler is complaining about it.

What would be the appropriate cast? Without referencing to the concrete class, I mean NOT like this:

```
if let foo2MaskChecked = foo2Mask as? Foo
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's something to do with type variance. Have a read of this: http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift

Comment: I see. The last example of the post illustrates the same problem. It seems that there is not a solution right now. Thanks!

Comment: @MikePollard Can you explain how variance comes into play here? We are not trying to pass off a `Container<T>` as a `Container<FooProtocol>`; all we try is to pass some `U: FooProtocol` to a method with signature `T: FooProtocol`. Intutitively, `U` and `T` unify, so all should be good. What am I missing?

Comment: Some days, I miss Scala.

Comment: FWIW, I thought that class protocols should be of help here, but no. [See this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596617/why-does-type-inference-in-swift-not-deal-with-transitive-constraints).

Comment: The problem is that [protocols don't conform to themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) – therefore you cannot use `FooProtocol` as a concrete type that conforms to `FooProtocol`.

Answer (score 0):

What it comes down to is the difference between `T: FooProtocol` and `FooProtocol` as @Hamish mentioned in his comment.

When I have a function like this:

```
func foo(_ i: FooProtocol)
```

I'm taking in an instance of type `FooProtocol`, so I can pass in a value that conforms to `FooProtocol` or its type is `FooProtocol`. This is similar to subclassing where you can pass both `SuperClass` and `SubClass` into `SuperClass`.

But if you have a function like this:

```
func foo<T>(_ i: T) where T: FooProtocol
```

I can pass in any type that conforms to `FooProtocol`, but because `FootProtocol` does not conform to itself, you can't pass that in.

So in your question, you are trying to pass in a type `FooProtocol` where the types must *conform* to `FooProtocol`. You could probably fix this by doing:

```
class Container {
    let someDataConformingFooProtocol: FooProtocol

    init(someDataConformingFooProtocol: FooProtocol) {
        self.someDataConformingFooProtocol = someDataConformingFooProtocol
    }
}

// Later
func createContainer(data: FooProtocol){
    Container(someDataConformingFooProtocol: data)
}
```