# Why does type inference in Swift not deal with transitive constraints?

Tags: swift, generics, type-inference, type-parameter

Tinkering around with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993714/swift-generics-and-type-constraints-strange-behavior), I came up with this:

```
class AllTogether<T: FooProtocol> {
    func createContainer<U: T>(data: U){
        Container<T>(someDataConformingFooProtocol: data)
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this should work if we make `FooProtocol` a class protocol:

```
protocol FooProtocol: class { ... }
```

However, we still get errors:

```
Error: inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'T'
Error: argument type 'U' does not conform to expected type 'FooProtocol'
```

Both messages seem to be wrong. What am I missing?

Is the subtype relation not transitive in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

The function adds an additional relation that is unnecessary.

Container is looking to be initialized with an object of type T.

If U is a subclass of T, then anything that can be called with

```
func createContainer<U: T>(data: U)
```

can also be called with

```
func createContainer(data: T)
```

So basically what the function is doing seems like it should be possible (and may be at some point. Swift's generics is due to be overhauled/improved) but it is pointless anyway.

Just use this instead:

```
func createContainer(data: T){
    Container<T>(someDataConformingFooProtocol: data)
}
```

Comment: You'll note that what you proposed is used in the question I link, and causes (similarly weird) errors elsewhere. In that case, what I do is not necessary. I guess I was thinking of signatures I saw in Scala's standard library. Off the top of my head, I can imagine signatures like `func foo<U: T, V: T>(u: U, v: V) where U: V` (for whatever travesty you'd need that) or, more simply, `func foo<U: T>(u: U) where U: Hashable` (or any other "utility" protocol `T` does not extend itself).

Comment: Come to think of it, `==<U: T>(lhs: U, rhs: U) where U: Equatable` seems a reasonable thing to want (be able to write down; not saying that would be the prefered way of defining that equality operator).

Comment: The plan is to add Conditional Conformance for Swift 4: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md  It seems likely this type of issue will be fixed then.

Comment: Yay! There seem to be many issues around type parameters in Swift, hopefully they'll fix a bunch along the way.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of quirks and holes in how generics and extensions work. hopefully it'll all be nice and tidy in the next year or two :)